# C# 'base' doesn't refer to the base class without explicit inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, tostring

```
class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {}

    public override string ToString() {
        return String.Format(
            "BaseType:\t{0}\nbase.toString:\t{1}",
            this.GetType().BaseType.ToString(),
            base.ToString());
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
}
```

The result is:

```
BaseType: System.Object
base.toString: TestesNET.Program+MyClass
```

Why doesn't `base.toString` shows `System.Object`?

Additional note: Java has this same behavior.

Answer (score 5):

`object`s implmentation of `.ToString()` is `GetType().ToString()`. Obviously, `GetType()` returns type of your class

See more in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

> Default implementations of the Object.ToString method return the fully
> qualified name of the object's type.

Answer (score 2):

The base object of all objects in C# type system is the `System.Object`.

Let that you declare a class called `Person` and then you declare a subclass of `Person` that is called `Student`. The base class of `Student` is the class called `Person` and the base class of `Person` is `System.Object`.

The base class `System.Object` has some methods that can be overidden from any custom class you define. One of these methods is called `ToString`. If you don't override it, then the default implementation of that method is called, when you call the `ToString` method on instances of your custom class.

So stepping into the default implementation of `ToString` method, would help us to answer your question. The default implementation can be found [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,52) and below for our convenience:

```
public virtual String ToString()
{
    return GetType().ToString();
}
```

Let's now make a move forward and examine what `this.GetType().BaseType.ToString()` should be expected to return.

Once more `GetType` is a method that is declared in the `System.Object`. However, this method cannot be overridden. Furthermore, it is implemented in the CLR **not** and not in the actual framework, hence it is marked as `extern`. It's implementation can be found [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,105). For our convenience, I included it also below:

```
// Returns a Type object which represent this object instance.
// 
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
[Pure]
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern Type GetType();
```

Based on comments, we expect a Type object to be returned, which represent this object instance. *Essentially* a `RuntimeType` object is returned, which is a subclass of `Type`. The class [Type](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,3d00eeab9feb80f3,references) is an abstract class. So it can't be instantiated. Then by looking what the `BaseType` property returns [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,394), we expect `System.Object` to be returned and then by calling the `ToString`, would return:

```
System.Object
```

Let's now think based on the above what we expect the call

```
base.ToString()
```

to return. Since the `base` of `MyClass` is `System.Object`, then code mentioned in ToString mentioned above would be executed. So the first call would be

```
GetType()
```

What's the type now ?

It's the same `RuntimeType` object returned in the call we make in the second argument we pass in `String.Format`. Hence, now the `ToString` that is overriden in `RuntimeType` class is called, whose implementation can be found [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/rttype.cs,5001) and below for our convenience:

```
public override String ToString() 
{
    return GetCachedName(TypeNameKind.ToString);
}
```

if we follow the code in that class, for the name method `GetCachedName`, it would be evident, why the string returned is that you mentioned in your question.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @PMF You were correct. For that reason, I deleted my answer and I rewritten it from the beginning.

Comment: This is a good answer now, even though I think it is a bit to detailed for a beginners question.

Comment: @PMF Thanks. Hope it would be more helpful with the included details rather than not including them.